# Range search filter for a specific column of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

i'm looking for a search filter that for example shows the ages between 12 and 40 from Age column in my table .

i was able to solve this by using datatable plugin range search but it messes up the scrolling and my sticky header and columns width and etc,

so i decided to don't spend my time fixing the datatable style issues and make a range search filter.
i looked everywhere for reference and examples and found nothing except datatables plugin range search.

this is the code :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
    var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
    var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
         ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
);

$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
$('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
    table.draw();
} );
} );
```

is there anyway to make this not depend on datatables plugin ?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Som you simply just want to filter out some `<tr>`'s in a `<table>` ...?

Comment: @davidkonrad yes , the ones that are not in range , i just started learning javascript , i don't know what i'm looking for ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning true or false in the custom filter tell DataTables if it should exclude or include the row. You can use jQuerys' `show()` and `hide()` to replicate the same behaviour:

```
$('#min, #max').keyup(function() {
   var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
   var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
   $('#example tbody tr').each(function() {
     var age = parseFloat( $('td:eq(3)', this).text() ) || 0; 
     if (( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max )) ||
         ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
         ( min <= age   && isNaN( max )) ||
         ( min <= age   && age <= max )) {
        $(this).show()
     } else {
        $(this).hide()
     }   
   })
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/c48z34xx/**

Comment: It worked like a charm , thank you sir ! you saved me countless hours of reading things i don't yet even understand :) , but i kinda figured out how this works based on your code , thanks alot.

Comment: this is client side search right ? is it faster than server side search using sql search queries ?

Comment: @MiLaDA You are welcome! We often just need to be pulled in the right direction. Yes, this is just an example to filter a pure dom <table>, nothing else. If you want more fancy stuff you should use DataTables.